# How to add an element to Global char *Array[]?

Tags: c++, arrays

How to add some element to globally declared char array & access the elements of the array from the another function?

I declared like this in source file

```
extern char *ArrayItems[] = {"Item1"};
```

**Function 1 - Add element into Array**

```
void AddSomeElementToGloablArray()
{
  ArrayItems[1] = "Item 2";
  ArrayItems[2] = "Item 3";
...
}
```

**Function 2 - Add again some element into Array**

```
void AddSomeElementToGloablArray()
{
  ArrayItems[3] = "Item 3";
  ArrayItems[4] = "Item 4";
...
}
```

**Main Function - To access the element of the array**

```
void Main()
{
  AddSomeElementToGloablArray();
  char *ItemValue = ArrayItems[3];
}
```

I tried like above code but it does not return added element. Here I cannot pass or return an array from function.
Please anybody help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
extern char *ArrayItems[] = {"Item1"};
```

I'm not sure if `extern` is needed here. If you only use it in a single source file, you don't need the `extern`. If you need to share the variable across multiple compilation units (source files), you should declare it in header file with `extern` keyword, and then declare the variable itself in any one of the source files.

```
/* shared.h */
extern char *ArrayItems[];
/* foo.c */
char *ArrayItems[] = {"Item1"};
```

Now, to add an element to array is not trivial. You need to do dynamic memory allocation. If you are using C++, it is highly recommended that you use `std::vector` instead. The following code works in standard compiler that support C++11.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

std::vector<char const *> ArrayItems = {"Item1"};

void AddSomething()
{
    ArrayItems.push_back("Foo");
    ArrayItems.push_back("Bar");
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << ArrayItems[0] << std::endl;
    AddSomething();
    std::cout << ArrayItems[1] << std::endl;
    std::cout << ArrayItems[2] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Item1
Foo
Bar
```

I use `char const *` instead of `char *` because `"Item1"` is a string literal, which shall not be modified on runtime anyway.

Answer (score 5):

> How to add an element to Global `char *Array[]`?

There is no way to add an element to an array. During the life time of an array its size never changes - no elements are ever added nor removed.

---

The way to solve this is indirection: Instead of a plain static/automatic array, we use a pointer to one and allocate that array dynamically. When you want more elements, we simply create a new, bigger array, copy (possibly by moving) the old elements into the new one and destroy the old array. This data structure is typically named "growable array" or "resizable array".

Of course, it would be madness to maintain bare pointers to a dynamic array, so we want to create a RAII wrapper class, with proper destructor etc. to make sure that the memory is handled properly. At this point I'm going to point out that such wrapper for a resizable array exists in the standard library, so there is no need for you to implement one yourself: `std::vector`.

---

> ```
> extern char *ArrayItems[] = {"Item1"};
> ```

This is ill-formed because a string literal can not be converted to a (non-const) `char*`.

> ```
> ArrayItems[1] = "Item 2";
> ```

This has undefined behaviour because the index is outside the bounds of the array.

Answer (score 1):

short answer: don't do that. use std::vector and call vector.push_back.

long answer: a global array declared with [] has fixed width, so you cannot just create a new member by accessing it's element number, this is extremely dangerous as you are accessing out of bounds memory.

Answer (score 0):

`extern` keyword does not allocate any memory for `ArrayItems`. It is only a **declaration** and not a definition. If this variable is declared in some other file in your project, and you want to use in the current file, you need to declare with extern keyword. If this variable is not defined in any other file, you can simply remove that keyword. Your code will work. However as suggested in the other answers, it is not a good idea to use global variables.